# Есть ли библиотеки для работы с большими датами и временем?

Tags: время, c++, дата

Добрый день.
Есть ли библиотеки для работы с большими датами и временем?
Григорианский календарь.
То есть раньше 0000 - и больше10000 годов.

Пробовал boost::date_time там ограничение 1400-10000.
Еще писал обёртку над Си time.h, но там точка отсчёта 1900.

[+] - обязательно
[!] - желательно
[-] - не обязательно

1. [+] Точные с учетом високосных годов.
2. [+] Стандартные операции(создание из определенного формата,сложение, вычитание, прибавление интервалов)
3. [!] Поддержка н.э и д.н.э.
4. [!] Поддержка веков.
5. [+] Поддержка часов минут секунд.
6. [!] Возможность задать интервал вручную.
7. [-] Выбор точности вручную(возможность задать 128 битные числа для секунд например).
8. [-] Производительность не важна.

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Коммерческие библиотеки рассматриваются?

Comment: @manking, если это Вам интересно (**особенно 128-разрядная арифметика**), то почему бы самому не написать?

--

Вот новый раздел открыли - *"исследования"*. В принципе, у Вас может интересная работа получиться.

Comment: Пишут, что [`QDateTime`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qdatetime.html#details) умеет:

> The range of valid dates is from January 2nd, 4713 BCE, to sometime in the year 11 million CE. The Julian Day returned by `QDate::toJulianDay()` is a number in the contiguous range from 1 to overflow, even across `QDateTime's` "date holes". It is suitable for use in applications that must convert a `QDateTime` to a date in another calendar system, e.g., Hebrew, Islamic or Chinese.

Comment: Есть, правда, подозрение, что корректное работа с датами до грегорианского календаря — это сложная задача.

Comment: @gecube 
нет нужна свободная.  
@avp
Времени много нет. Но видимо придется писать. Чтобы не портить этот вопрос напишу в исследованиях.
@Котик_хочет_кушать 
Qt не могу использовать.

Comment: @manking, а удовлетворите естественное любопытство.

Если не ошибаюсь, то 64 разрядов достаточно, для представления интервалов в секундах, начиная с Большого Взрыва (15 млрд. лет).

Зачем Вам 128-разрядная арифметика?

Comment: У меня только одно объяснение - человек сделал машину времени и ему нужно софт дописать.

Comment: Ну имеется ввиду что обычно можно указать тип хранения секунд.
то есть unsigned int , long long , или сторонний тип у которого перегруженны требуемые операторы.
Я об этом не особо думал, поэтому указал что это не обязательно. 
Сейчас вижу, что чем больше период тем больше нагрузка на производительность, так как надо считать года по одному.

@KoVadim 
Если кто то решит создать игру про путешествие во времени до большого взрыва, то этот код может ему пригодится.

Comment: Действительно, об играх я не догадался.

Comment: самое лучшее используйте long long и все. Все вычисляете в миллисекундах. Как в линуксе.

Answer (score 1):

как подсказали в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/210161/#comment210300_210161), класс [`QDateTime`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html) поддерживает интервал +/- 292 миллиона лет (относительно начала эры).